# Getting "Assertion `args[1]->IsInt32()' failed" running npm start, no error when running node index.js instead

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a `package.json` file set up with the following:

```
...,
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "test": "mocha"
},
...
```

So I'm trying to run it with `npm start`.  Unfortunately, it's giving me the following error output:

```
npm[7444]: src\node_file.cc:1599: Assertion `args[1]->IsInt32()' failed.
 1: 00007FF75D44121A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4810
 2: 00007FF75D41A5B6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF75D41A66F node::MakeCallback+4703
 4: 00007FF75D3DF663 uv_loop_fork+34595
 5: 00007FF75DC45782 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+60562
 6: 00007FF75DC46C1D v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+65837
 7: 00007FF75DC45C79 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+61833
 8: 00007FF75DC45B5B v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+61547
 9: 000002E4183DC5C1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! c4sk@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the c4sk@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-11T04_52_55_255Z-debug.log
```

For reasons I cannot begin to fathom, this is only happening on one machine.  Also, while `npm start` fails with this error, simply skipping npm and running `node index.js` works fine.

All machines have fresh installs of Node.js v10.15.0

What ... on earth?

In case it would help, here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "c4sk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": /**/,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "/**/"
  },
  "author": "Steven Kitzes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "/**/"
  },
  "homepage": "/**/",
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "readline-sync": "^1.4.9"
  }
}
```

**Update:** I have traced the problem down to the `readline-sync` package (or perhaps one of its dependencies).  I switched to another package for CLI input (the `prompt` package) and was able to get my application going.  The next time I have access to my home machine I will update with the logs requested in the comments to see if we can get to the bottom of the issue with `readline-sync`.

Comment: could you please post the output log for understanding issue more. `C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-11T04_52_55_255Z-debug.log`

Comment: `readline-sync` needs a TTY to work: see [#77](https://github.com/anseki/readline-sync/issues/77#issuecomment-462098739)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to node version 14. You can use `nvm` to manage node versions.